# ibdata1 back to it's original size after deleting it

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have followed the following steps in order to save space but I am surprised after restarting MySQL `ibdata1` gets back to it's original size.

> As you want to reclaim the space from `ibdata1` you actually have to
>   delete the file:
>
> 1. Do a `mysqldump` of all databases, procedures, triggers etc **except the `mysql` and `performance_schema` databases**
> 2. Drop all databases **except the above 2 databases**
> 3. Stop mysql
> 4. Delete `ibdata1` and `ib_log` files
> 5. Start mysql
> 6. Restore from dump

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql)

Comment: This question has got nothing to do with sw development, this is a pure admin question, therefore it is off topic here on SO. You may get more help at the DBA site.

Comment: Why down vote? At least explain.

Comment: Did you drop/delete any tables/db that you don't want before you mysqldump all the databases?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have `innodb_file_per_table = ON`?

Regardless of the above setting, `ibdata1` will have some stuff in it.  Without more specifics (size of that file, the above setting, number of tables, number of `.ibd` files, etc.), I cannot be more specific.

In my opinion, "tiny" tables may as well be built with file_per_table = OFF.

Comment: It takes a lot of attention to manage file_per_table differently per table on the same MySQL instance, because when you ALTER TABLE or OPTIMIZE TABLE, the table will be copied with respect to the current file_per_table setting. It's too easy to slurp a huge table into ibdata1 by accident, which will increase its size irreversibly.